# Datatrigger after insert - insert into a table ON ANOTHER SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two separate SQL servers, let's call them A_server and B_server. When there is an insert/delete/update on the A_server, the row should be inserted/deleted/updated on the B_server. I have found a ton of examples, on how to code the data trigger when both tables are on the SAME server, e.g.:

```
CREATE TRIGGER yourNewTrigger ON yourSourcetable
FOR INSERT
AS
   INSERT INTO yourDestinationTable
   (col1, col2    , col3, user_id, user_name)
   SELECT 'a'
        , default
        , null
        , user_id
        , user_name
   FROM inserted
GO
```

But I haven't found any example of a data trigger where it's done between tables on DIFFERENT servers. Where does the connection string go exactly and what does it look like?

Comment: Do you have a [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql) configured? The syntax goes like [linkedservername].[databasename].[schemaname].[tablename]

Comment: While you *can* do this with linked servers and triggers, you'll end up with distributed transactions. If your scenario involves a simple copy of the row (no interesting processing) consider using [transactional replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication).

Comment: did you consider replication ?

Comment: You can technically use a linked server as Jacob H suggests. Please don't By doing so you're introducing distributed transactions with major performance implications against your insert operations. Can you possibly use periodically fired stored procedures, CDC or replication to sync your database instances?

Comment: It's not a simple replication of a table row, there's more coding logic into it, so replication won't work unfortunately. @Pete M, will a data trigger cause performance implications if there won't be very much traffic? And if I use a fired procedure (don't know what CDC is), will I have to configure a linked server too?

Comment: What do you mean "please don't". You don't know anything about this persons hardware, or requirements. You use "distributed transactions" like it's a dirty word and bad practice. Which isn't a rule by any means, and would depend on information that you don't have available from this post. And also is much more work. My response is the only answer to the question that was asked. But carry on...

Comment: Note that, even if some transformation logic is involved, replication remains an option because you can specify that `INSERT` should be done using a custom stored procedure. That said, that use case is definitely not as comfortable as "straight" replication.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you.

First, create a linked server

```
use master
exec sp_addlinkedserver
   @server='NameOf_LinkedServer', 
   @srvproduct='',
   @provider='SQLNCLI', 
   @datasrc='yourServer\instance1';
```

and then point to it

```
CREATE TRIGGER yourNewTrigger ON yourSourcetable
FOR INSERT
AS
   INSERT INTO NameOf_LinkedServer.DataBaseName.Owner.yourDestinationTable
   (col1, col2    , col3, user_id, user_name)
   SELECT 'a'
        , default
        , null
        , user_id
        , user_name
   FROM inserted
```